# Automatically push JavaDoc pages to GitHub using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, github, javadoc, github-pages

I've created a repository on GitHub and pushed a couple of classes to it succesfully using Netbeans 7.3.

However, I'd like to push the JavaDoc-generated HTML documentation for these classes to GitHub so that they show up as browsable pages for visitors to the project page (on GitHub).

I've seen a (small) number of guides online offering ways to achieve this using the command line (such as [this blog](http://assylias.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/upload-javadoc-to-github/)) but they seem to require the console.

Is there an elegant way to use the Netbeans interface to generate JavaDoc pages and then push them to a gh-pages branch for the project on GitHub so that documentation stays up to date with each push of the actual class files?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant way to use the Netbeans interface to generate
>   JavaDoc pages

Netbeans uses Apache Ant under the cover, so you should find a `build.xml` in your project directory.

The `build.xml` imports the larger ant script `nbproject/build-impl.xml` but offers a lot of hooks that let you add behaviors to default actions implemented in the larger script.

If you were creating a jar, for example, you would may add in the `build.xml` a target that generates the javadoc just before creating the jar:

```
<target name="-pre-jar">
  <javadoc sourcepath="${source.dir}" destdir="apidocs"/>
</target>
```

If you want a more sophisticated level of automation you should consider Maven or Gradle: they let you generate whatever artifact you want, generate a site, deploy the site to a remote server.